# Bounding $e^{3iz}$ for $z\in \mathbb{C}$

Tags: complex-analysis

So I initially thought that $$|e^{3iz}|\leq1$$ since I have seen online that $\cos^2(3z)+\sin^2(3z)=1$ still holds for $z\in \mathbb{C}$.
However, I am also finding that $e^{3iz}=e^{3i(x+iy)}=e^{3ix-3y}$. So $$|e^{3iz}|=|e^{3ix}||e^{-3y}|=e^{-3y}$$ and now if we take $y=-1$ then we find that $$|e^{3iz}|=e^3.$$ Any ideas what is happening here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is indeed true that $\cos^2(z) + \sin^2(z) = 1$ for $z \in \mathbb C$, but that doesn't make them bounded.  Remember that the square of a complex number can be negative.  If $\sin^2(z) < 0$, $\cos^2(z) > 1$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** $\left| e^{z}\right| = e^{\operatorname{Re} z}$. So what is $\operatorname{Re}  3iz$?

Answer (score 0):

Nothing spooky. This is true: 
$$\forall z \in \mathbb{C} \qquad\cos^{2}(z) + \sin^2(z) = 1$$
So is this: 
$$\forall z \in \mathbb{C} \qquad e^{z} = \cos(z) + i\sin(z) $$
But since $\cos(z)$ and $\sin(z)$ are not generally real, it is **not** true that
$$|e^{z}| = \cos^{2}(z) + \sin^{2}(z)$$
For complex $z$, $e^{z}$, $\sin(z)$ and $\cos(z)$ are all unbounded. Indeed, the sequence $z_{n} = in$ has
$$|\cos(z_{n})| = \frac{1}{2}(e^{n} + e^{-n}) \ge \frac{1}{2}e^{n}$$